# Nextjs ISR with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Our application uses ISR and we have deployed it on Elastic Beanstalk.  The problem we are facing is that the autoscaling feature of Elastic Beanstalk is causing incremental revalidation changes to "disappear".  The default setting for the auto scaling is to spawn a new instance if the outbound network traffic reaches 6mb and to remove an instance if outbound network traffic falls below 2mb.  On our test and staging servers where network traffic is low, we are seeing new instances being created and removed.  What is happening is that any new content from revalidation after the build is not showing up in the new instances.  We tried setting:

```
  experimental: {
    isrMemoryCacheSize: 0,
  },
```

but that didn't do anything.  Can any suggest way to address this situation?  What might be the best practice for setting the auto scaling triggers?  Or is there a way to sync the cache between nodes/instances?

Thanks!